# Exercise on the Lebesgue measure

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, rational-numbers

*Let be  $|*|:S\rightarrow [0, +\infty]$ the Lebesgue measure on the $\mathbb{R}$ set, $\{q_n:n\geq1\}=\mathbb{Q}$ and the functions:
$$  \begin{equation}
    \gamma(t) =
    \begin{cases}
      \frac1{\sqrt{t}} & 0<|t|<1 \\
      0& |t|=0 \  \lor |t|>1 
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation} $$
$$f(t)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{5^n}\gamma(t-q_n)$$
with $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that:
$$a) \ f(t)<+\infty\  almost\  everywhere \ in \ \mathbb{R} \ and \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f=1$$
$$b) \ f\ is \ bounded \ in \ every \ interval \ I \subset\ \mathbb{R} \ that \ \mathring I \neq \emptyset$$
$$c) \ Even \ if \ the \ f \ function \ is \ modified \ on \ a \ negligible \ set \ the \ (b) \ propery\ \  still\ holds$$*

I managed to integrate $\int_\mathbb{R}\gamma(t)dt=4$ then I showed that, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is a negligible set: $$\int_\mathbb{R}f_n(t)dt=\int_\mathbb{R}\frac1{5^n}\gamma(t-q_n)dt=\int_\mathbb{R}\frac1{5^n}\gamma(s)ds=\frac4{5^n}$$
Then using the monotone convergence theorem I proved that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)dt=1$.
I actually have no idea how to visualize and prove (a) and (b).

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: I'm gonna update the question.